# Most of the query plans recreated in the past 4 hours

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, sp-blitzcache, query-performance

I have got a problem with my SQL Server database's performance. I have found this tool [sp_BlitzCache](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/). After command's executing, I got this statement:

> You have 92.00% plans created in the past 24 hours, and 92.00% created in the past 4 hours.

While I identified the problem (using SQL Server Profiler, I have checked StmtRecompile event occurrences), I was able to find only a few full-text search queries that are often rebuilt. However, full-text search queries represent just about 5% of all queries.

Do you have any suggestions what might cause the recreation of the remaining 87% plans?

I have got SQL Server 2012 (version 11.0.6567.0).

**Edit: I have added my performance counters**

```
+---------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------+
|        object_name        |          counter_name          |  cntr_value  |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------+
| SQLServer:Buffer Manager  | Background writer pages/sec    |            0 |
| SQLServer:Buffer Manager  | Buffer cache hit ratio         |        28436 |
| SQLServer:Buffer Manager  | Buffer cache hit ratio base    |        28436 |
| SQLServer:Buffer Manager  | Checkpoint pages/sec           |      8259452 |
| SQLServer:Buffer Manager  | Database pages                 |      4434337 |
| SQLServer:Buffer Manager  | Free list stalls/sec           |            9 |
| SQLServer:Buffer Manager  | Integral Controller Slope      |            0 |
| SQLServer:Buffer Manager  | Lazy writes/sec                |         5608 |
| SQLServer:Buffer Manager  | Page life expectancy           |       438901 |
| SQLServer:Buffer Manager  | Page lookups/sec               | 122694703703 |
| SQLServer:Buffer Manager  | Page reads/sec                 |     60994608 |
| SQLServer:Buffer Manager  | Page writes/sec                |    126076564 |
| SQLServer:Buffer Manager  | Readahead pages/sec            |     45305420 |
| SQLServer:Buffer Manager  | Target pages                   |    130990080 |
| SQLServer:Buffer Node     | Database pages                 |      4434337 |
| SQLServer:Buffer Node     | Page life expectancy           |       438901 |
| SQLServer:Buffer Node     | Local node page lookups/sec    |            0 |
| SQLServer:Buffer Node     | Remote node page lookups/sec   |            0 |
| SQLServer:Memory Manager  | External benefit of memory     |            0 |
| SQLServer:Memory Manager  | Connection Memory (KB)         |         3304 |
| SQLServer:Memory Manager  | Database Cache Memory (KB)     |     35474784 |
| SQLServer:Memory Manager  | Free Memory (KB)               |     13229808 |
| SQLServer:Memory Manager  | Granted Workspace Memory (KB)  |            0 |
| SQLServer:Memory Manager  | Lock Memory (KB)               |       455928 |
| SQLServer:Memory Manager  | Lock Blocks Allocated          |      1798154 |
| SQLServer:Memory Manager  | Lock Owner Blocks Allocated    |      3568588 |
| SQLServer:Memory Manager  | Lock Blocks                    |        10562 |
| SQLServer:Memory Manager  | Lock Owner Blocks              |        10617 |
| SQLServer:Memory Manager  | Maximum Workspace Memory (KB)  |     43368000 |
| SQLServer:Memory Manager  | Memory Grants Outstanding      |            0 |
| SQLServer:Memory Manager  | Memory Grants Pending          |            0 |
| SQLServer:Memory Manager  | Optimizer Memory (KB)          |         1400 |
| SQLServer:Memory Manager  | Reserved Server Memory (KB)    |            0 |
| SQLServer:Memory Manager  | SQL Cache Memory (KB)          |       229112 |
| SQLServer:Memory Manager  | Stolen Server Memory (KB)      |      8063232 |
| SQLServer:Memory Manager  | Log Pool Memory (KB)           |         4192 |
| SQLServer:Memory Manager  | Target Server Memory (KB)      |     56934400 |
| SQLServer:Memory Manager  | Total Server Memory (KB)       |     56767824 |
| SQLServer:Memory Node     | Database Node Memory (KB)      |     35474784 |
| SQLServer:Memory Node     | Free Node Memory (KB)          |     13229808 |
| SQLServer:Memory Node     | Foreign Node Memory (KB)       |            0 |
| SQLServer:Memory Node     | Stolen Node Memory (KB)        |      8063208 |
| SQLServer:Memory Node     | Target Node Memory (KB)        |     56934376 |
| SQLServer:Memory Node     | Total Node Memory (KB)         |     56767800 |
+---------------------------+--------------------------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Maybe someone ran DBCC FREEPROCCACHE? :P

Comment: @DanielBjörk I am the only person that have permission to do things like this so I do not think it is the reason. However, I will check it.

Comment: Are you using parametrized queries or stored procedures? or is the problem that you have string / number literals in your SQL, and therefore plans can't be re-used?

Comment: @JamesZ Yes, I'm using a lot of parametrized queries. The tool that I have mentioned in my post, BlitzCache, says that I have got a problem with parameter sniffing.

Comment: Are you rebuilding indexes or updating statistics nightly? Maybe there's memory pressure on the server?

Comment: @sp_BlitzErik I'm rebuilding all things like indexes and statistics once a week.

Comment: Can you verify when the SQL Server service was restarted last time. Easiest way is look in then SQL Error log. Look at the end of the log files for a log with the SQL server version.

Answer (score 7):

The query used to test plan creation time is this

```
WITH x AS (
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, deqs.creation_time, SYSDATETIME()) <= 24 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [plans_24],
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, deqs.creation_time, SYSDATETIME()) <= 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [plans_4],
       SUM(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(HOUR, deqs.creation_time, SYSDATETIME()) <= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [plans_1],
       COUNT(deqs.creation_time) AS [total_plans]
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS deqs
)
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(3,2), NULLIF(x.plans_24, 0) / (1. * NULLIF(x.total_plans, 0))) * 100 AS [percent_24],
       CONVERT(DECIMAL(3,2), NULLIF(x.plans_4 , 0) / (1. * NULLIF(x.total_plans, 0))) * 100 AS [percent_4],
       CONVERT(DECIMAL(3,2), NULLIF(x.plans_1 , 0) / (1. * NULLIF(x.total_plans, 0))) * 100 AS [percent_1],
       @@SPID AS SPID
INTO #plan_creation
FROM x
OPTION (RECOMPILE) ;
```

also the SP provides some clues as well on where to start your further research

> If these percentages are high, it may be a sign of memory pressure or plan cache instability

Other than above clues,check if your server has been restarted   .

if your server is not restarted,then below is the approach i would take

- check if your facing memory pressure

First see ,if your memory settings are configured optimally.if so ,you can use below counters to see if you are facing memory pressure

> Memory: Available MB
> SQL Buffer: Free Pages
> SQL Buffer: Page Life
> SQL Buffer: Lazy Writes

if you are facing memory pressure,then you can see and tune the queries which are using more memory or try adding more memory

> [you might have ran queries that causes recompilation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181055(v=sql.105).aspx#Anchor_1)  .some of them include

- Changes made to a table or view referenced by the query (ALTER TABLE and ALTER VIEW).
- Changes made to a single procedure, which would drop all plans for that procedure from the cache (ALTER PROCEDURE).
- Changes to any indexes used by the execution plan
- Updates on statistics used by the execution plan, generated either explicitly from a statement, such as UPDATE STATISTICS, or generated automatically.
- Dropping an index used by the execution plan.

you can also see this white paper for more details on Plan caching

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee343986(v=sql.100).aspx

Comment: I have added my performance counters, could you help me interpret this values?

Comment: you can look out for detailed memory related counters here :https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/teekamg/2007/11/06/sql-server-memory-related-performance-counters/

Comment: @TheGameiswar you say "you might have ran queries that causes recompilation... such as changes to index, update on statistics". If I do index reorg/rebuild based on fragmentation + update statistics every night, do that mean the my plans will all be (or almost all) recreated every day? is that a problem?

Answer (score 2):

To add what @TheGameiswar said you can also run this query to see the details of plans that are not obtained from cache.

```
;with
    xmlnamespaces (N'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan' as DYN)
select
    db_name(st.dbid) as DBName
    , object_schema_name(st.objectid, st.dbid) as SchemaName
    , object_name(st.objectid, st.dbid) as ObjectName
    , ecp.objtype
    , st.text
    , qp.query_plan.value('(/DYN:ShowPlanXML/DYN:BatchSequence/DYN:Batch/DYN:Statements/DYN:StmtSimple/@RetrievedFromCache)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as RetrievedFromCache
    , qp.query_plan
into #temp
from sys.dm_exec_cached_plans ecp
    outer apply sys.dm_exec_query_plan(ecp.plan_handle) qp
    outer apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(ecp.plan_handle) st

select
    *
from #temp t
where t.RetrievedFromCache is null
    and t.DBName is not null
order by t.DBName, t.SchemaName, t.ObjectName;
```